# Должно ли быть максимальное значение в диапазоне включительно?

Tags: java

Когда я работаю с методами, которые на вход принимают некие диапазоны значений, всегда остается неуверенность в том, является ли максимальное значение включительно.

Например, такой метод:

```
    /**
     * Нарисовать квадрат.
     */
    public void drawSquare(int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY, Color color) {
        ...
    }
```

Этот метод рисует в окне квадрат. Параметры `minX` и `minY` означают минимальную точку квадрата. Параметры `maxX` и `maxY` означают максимальную точку для рисования квадрата, но включительно ли?

Если я захочу нарисовать квадрат длиною 10 пикселей, какой вариант api предпочтительнее (`length = 10`):

1. `drawSquare(x, y, x + length, y + length, RED)` - не включительно
2. `drawSquare(x, y, x + length - 1, y + length - 1, RED)` - включительно, приходится делать -1, чтобы не закрасило 11-й пиксель

Метод `drawSquare` это лишь пример. Меня интересует, какой подход считается более правильным. Какой подход использовать при создании своих методов.

Comment: Хороший вопрос) посмотрю, что ответят остальные) а в стандартных библиотеках у параметров чаще всего диапазон  "от" (включая), "до" (не включая).

Comment: @SergeyZh. Смотря какая функция. Если генерация чисел, то может быть и не включая. А если рисование фигур, то включая.

Comment: @Эникейщик а почему именно так? как понять, что лучше подходит в той или иной ситуации?

Comment: А почему по минимальному у вас не возникает вопросов?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець потому что минимум всегда встречается включительно.